# Overloading association methods

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Does anyone know if there is a way to overload an association accessor method and not the setter?

For example

```
class Bar
  has_many :users

  def users
    'foo'
  end

end

a = Bar.new
a.users # => 'foo'
a.users << bob => [bob]
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You might want to start accepting other people answers... 6 questions and no accept given.

Answer (score 1):

Ok can't do it.

I'm overloading the method that accesses the association proxy object.

Oh well live an learn.